# npm doesn't work with latest stable node?

Tags: node.js, npm

I am really new to node/npm, but I upgraded my node (I don't even remember why at this point) when I was trying to install a logging solution (which aren't compatible with 0.10 anyway) and now npm doesn't work I get this:

```
Error: npm doesn't work with node v0.10.26
```

I didn't find any question or answer to this. Since I can't use npm at all I can't npm upgrade or npm remove. Node is awesome, but it is very confusing sometimes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest npm version should always work with the latest stable Node.js version. Update npm as well.

For the [n](https://github.com/visionmedia/n) version manager, the best solution seems to be to reinstall npm from npmjs.org:

```
curl -L https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
```

Comment: I just uninstalled and reinstalled npm using apt-get and I get the same error. As I said I can't npm upgrade because I can't run npm. How do I upgrade it?

Comment: @PixMach How did you update Node? The versions installed by apt should work fine together. Also, `npm upgrade` does not update npm itself, just the packages installed by npm.

Comment: I am not sure "sudo n stable" i think

Comment: I get:

sh: 1: cannot open html: No such file
sh: 2: Syntax error: redirection unexpected

Comment: Fixed it! After much experimentation the curl can use -L to use the redirect: sudo curl -L https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh Thanks!

Comment: I also had to do `sudo sh` after the pipe.

Comment: I am using node v6.10.0 which comes with npm 3.10.10. However, the latest npm is 4.3.0 and should I use the latest one or just stick with npm 3.10.10?? Thanks.